# How to identify if all numbers in list are the same or different if the list length is unknown (Python)?

Tags: python

I'm using Python and I'm trying to figure out how to ascertain whether all numbers in a list are the same or different (even with just one integer being different) if beforehand I don't know the total number of elements in the list. Initially I wrote something like:

```
def equalOrNot(lst):
    if sum(lst)%len(lst)==0:
         return False
    else:
         return True
```

But it's not working in all cases. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Check the duplicate post, your approach does not work for all case, for example `lst = [1,2,3]`

Comment: Your solution should fail when `sum(lst)` is multiple of `len(lst)` and all numbers are not equal.

Answer (score 6):

Use `set`:

```
if len(set(lst)) == 1:
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can use the builtin `all()`

```
all(numbers[0] == number for number in numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
def equalOrNot(lst):
    for item in lst[1:]:
        if item != lst[0]:
            return False

    return True
```

Or just do:

```
lst[::-1] == sorted(lst)
```

Comment: Your 2nd proposition doesn't work if lst is already sorted.

Comment: @cromod missing `[::-1]`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if lst.count(lst[0]) == len(lst):
```

or

```
if lst.reverse() == lst.sort():
```